# Neo4j indexes with wildcard searches on properties

Tags: performance, indexing, neo4j, lucene, cypher

We are using Neo4j Community Edition 2.3.1, and have many queries which use wildcards. For example, we search for all 'User' that have the word 'cars' in a couple larger properties: Profile and Bio ( ie: sentences or small paragraphs ).

```
MATCH (user:User) 
WHERE (user.Profile =~ '(?i).* cars .*') OR (user.Bio =~ '(?i).* cars .*')
RETURN user SKIP 0 LIMIT 20;
```

The number of 'User' nodes is over 1.6 million.

The queries are relatively slow, although this is known by us, as Neo4j uses a AllNodesScan, as there are no indexes on the properties. We'd like to create an index for this query, but Neo4j 'new' indexes do not work with wildcards.

We are thinking to use the 'old' fulltext Neo4j indexes with Lucene.
Also thinking of making Bio and Profile into labeled Nodes, instead of Properties, then using a Schema index on them.

I'm concerned implementing 'legacy' indexes, as they are, well 'legacy' and I'm thinking about whether they could be deprecated at some point.

Suggestions on improving performance on the wildcard search above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding using 'CONTAINS', it cannot be used with new Schema Indexes as per the [Neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-use-index-with-starts-with). But thanks for the suggestion.

I'm going to answer, and mark this as 'answered'. Our team implemented [Legacy Indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html) in Neo4j, and it is working wonders. Simple queries execution times are down from ~6seconds to <100ms.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. Apparently only STARTS WITH relies on indexes yet. This might probably change in the future. I'm going to edit my answer just in case.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Suggested using CONTAINS but only STARTS WITH currently uses schema indexes. This might change in future versions.

Have you tried using the new `CONTAINS` operator added in Neo4j 2.3?

```
MATCH (user:User) 
WHERE user.Profile CONTAINS "cars" OR user.Bio CONTAINS "cars"
RETURN user SKIP 0 LIMIT 20;
```

You should a schema index on every String property you want to do string filtering on.